# Pandas groupby and fill in zero values with non-zero values by each group

Tags: group-by

I'm trying to fill all the zero values by a single non-zero values in each group of a large dataframe.

Below is a small example Pandas dataframe that outlines the problem. One hour of each day has a non-zero value and the other hours have a zero value.

To set up the dataframe:

```
    data = {
        'week': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        'day': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
        'hour': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
        'value': [0,123,0,456,0,0,0,789,0]
        }
simple = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The dataframe:

| week | day | hour | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 123 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 456 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 789 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 0 |

I'd like to fill all the zero values of each day by the one non-zero value of each day so the updated dataframe would look like this. This could also be done with a new column for the filled values if necessary.

| week | day | hour | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 123 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 123 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 456 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 456 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 456 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 789 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 789 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 789 |

Comment: What is logic about values of non zero values? I mean it would be a random value or a value based on something else?

Comment: It's a value based on something else that created this type of format in a much larger dataframe. I just tried to create a toy example to make the problem as easy as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I found the answer I needed through a groupby max transform. Here's the code that workded for what I needed. It created the target dataframe I was trying to achieve above.

```
simple['value'] = simple.groupby(['week', 'day'])['value'].transform(max)
```